# Powershell.exe No Output

Tags: powershell

For my script I have 2 files in this folder and they both have the same file name so my 1st script can call my second script.

1st file (to my understanding) is a batch file that allows me to run my PS script as admin.

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
PAUSE
```

2nd file is where I will be writing my PowerShell script. In my case I want my whole script to print out the current mapped drives, then with user input remove the unwanted drives, and then add any new drives if desired. And so far I am stuck with trying to print out current mapped drives because everytime I execute my batch file it executes my PS file and the PS.exe console is blank with no output of any kind. It only giving an output if I was to run it PS ISE but not in PS.exe, am i missing something?

```
$e = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select Name, ProviderName
Write-Output $e
write-output "$e"
Write-Output "test"
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Comment: Why do you run the script as admin? Without modifying the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` nad value `EnableLinkedConnections` you won't have access to user mode mappings.

Comment: I am running as admin because the final PS scrip will be renaming the computer and the current user wont have admin rights. So my though process is have (Non-Admin)user login run the .bat that will run the PS as admin to map drive and rename the computer. I will be physically by the computer as well.

Granted I could do that all by hand but there are over 40 different user that I have to do this to.

Answer (score 0):

To have access to user mode mappings when running as admin
you have to set a registry value

Batch code to set that registry key

```
:: Keep Net Use Drives in UAC Mode
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
Reg Add "%Key%" /f /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit more? How would that allow me to print out `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select Name, ProviderName` on PS.exe? Would i just add that to my current batch file and have it run all together or would i have to run that before hand.

Comment: You rrun the batch file once, not sure if you've to logout and in again and when elevating you should have access to the mappings from the user.