# UNC path (to remote directory) becomes inaccessible in Elevated/Admin PS session

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server

I always accessed a network location, using UNC path (with Hidden-Share) using normal `Set-Location` cmdlet (see example below) which works fine, but when I run the PS session **as Admin**, the UNC path becomes inaccessible, can someone please explain why?

Example:

**In Non-admin session:**

```
PS C:\> cd \\srv01\c$\Temp\
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv01\c$\Temp>  *notice: prompt changed to show remote location*
```

**Elevated PowerShell session (Run as Administrator):**

```
PS C:\> cd \\srv01\c$\Temp\
cd : Cannot find path '\\srv01\c$\Temp\' because it does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53396923/6811411) to a recent similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vista UAC - Trouble Mapping Network Drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267085/vista-uac-trouble-mapping-network-drives)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, why do I need to alter the Windows registry to access a path that is accessible for a normal non-admin user, doesn't make sense for Admin to have more restrictive access. By default, does admin's "LinkedConnections" kept blocked? Is there a more elegant approach (other than altering the registry key? Thanks.

Comment: Mappings you create as a user aren't by default also usable when elevating. This registry entry changes this behaviour. Maybe this can also be done with a GPO.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, say your user account is member of Domain-Admin group, who has access to certain network-resources (including Hidden-shares e.g. "c$" as in UNC paths), but when you start an elevated session (i.e. an Admin-Prompt), you actually are impersonating a local-admin account, i.e. you are not seen/treated as your user account, therefore the network resources that were shared with you become inaccessible in that elevated-session (and only the resources that are accessible to the local-admin will remain available). This behaviour can  be altered using the Windows registry as below:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System EnableLinkedConnections =(dword)1
```

Hope this helps others.